# YouTube Analytics API Reports query: 400 bad request

Tags: google-apis-explorer, youtube-analytics-api

As a content owner I would like to retrieve reports by using the reports.query method in the YouTube Analytics API. When I execute the request the error is: **badRequest** with the message *The query is not supported*. Code 400.

I fill in the following fields:

- ids: contentOwner==MyContentOwnerId
- start-date:2017-08-01
- end-date:2017-08-10
- metrics:views

Why do I receive the 400 error? Thanks for your time!

Robert

Answer (score 2):

I tried your query and I got the same bad request error, however when I filter it down to the video level it provides me with the information I needed.

ids: contentOwner==ContentOwnerId
start-date: 2017-08-01
end-date:2017-08-10
metrics:views
dimension:day
filter:video==videoId

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank Nguyen! I forgot to filter down the results by channel or by video :)